# JavaScript location redirect stalls AJAX call on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

This is an issue I'm facing only on Chrome.

Code snippets -

```
// Bind methods to global AJAX events
jQuery(document).bind({
    ajaxStart : function() {
        showWaitMessage(); // this is where it hangs
    },
    ajaxStop : function() {
        hideWaitMessage();
    },
    ajaxError : function(jqXHR, exception) {
            // error handling
    }
});
```

The location redirect -

```
var href = "downloadPack?clientName="+clientName+"&clientID="+clientID+"&fundName="+fundName+"&fundID="+fundID+"&navDate="+navDate+"&KD="+KD+"&status="+status;
//setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = href;}, 500);
//window.location.href = href;
jQuery(location).attr('href', href);    // Have tried the above two lines too (same issue)
```

The AJAX call -

```
function getExceptions() {
    jQuery.ajax({url:"exceptions",success:function(result){
        jQuery('#subApp').html(result);
        document.getElementById("subLink1").className = "";
        document.getElementById("subLink2").className = "selected";
        document.getElementById("subLink3").className = "last_item";
        if(jQuery("#fund").val() == 'all')
            jQuery('#fund').val(jQuery('#fund option').filter(function() { return jQuery(this).html() == selectedFund;}).val());
        jQuery('#fund option[value="all"]').prop('disabled', true);
        getNavDates(0);
    }});
}
```

The loaction redirect is not used to go to a different page, but to trigger a download.
This is when I face the problem in Chrome-

> 1. Click the download link(location redirect).
> 2. Call the AJAX function.
> 3. AJAX call hangs at showWaitMessage();
> 4. Download goes on as usual.

Note: Everything works fine on other browsers. The AJAX call on Chrome also works fine if I do that before hitting the download link.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this problem – use hidden iframe for downloading instead of current window. Just define this simple function:

```
var $idown;  // Keep it outside of the function, so it's initialized once.
function downloadURL(url) {
    if ($idown) {
        $idown.attr('src', url);
    } else {
        $idown = $('<iframe>', { id: 'idown', src: url }).hide().appendTo('body');
    }
}
```

And replace your line:

```
jQuery(location).attr('href', href);
```

With:

```
downloadURL(href);
```